# Missing Partition With Recovery Files

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-7-backup

I have a 3TB internal hard drive. It was an MBR initialized disk (which doesn't support hard drives over 2TB. You can however use a scheme to make the 3rd Terabyte its own partition. I did so by using Seagate's DiscWizard. I used the 3rd Terabyte for backups and I had a very recent one there. I refreshed my computer to factory conditions because the process said it would only affect its partition. However, now with a fresh operating system, I am only able to see the 2TB my OS sits in. My question is, has all the data on the 1 TB partition been lost or, if it is still there but hidden, can I recover it? Thank you for all your help. I am running Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Try this: open Disk Management by searching that in the start screen. Check to see if there are two partitions listed under your disk. If there are, right click the 1TB partition and click `Assign drive letters and paths...`. Here, choose a drive letter for the partition and `OK` out of everything. The partition should now be visible.

Comment: The disk wizard uses tricks on the first few disk block things to accomplish the goal you desired, when you wipe or repair the area change the partition table, that change is lost The trick used to create the partitions/tables in that method no longer there. The data that would be on specific sectors of the drive are not lost yet.   IF you had a BackUp of all the data, I would suggest your recreate the original scenario using the software that did that trick, but it is unknown if in the change and any formatting would start actually wiping data.

Answer (score -1):

*having less than 50 reps, I can't make comments*

I'm confident TestDisk from CG Security will help you get your data easily.

It's free. Donload it from this page: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

After selecting the type of the disk (intel PC) then select analyze once it has finished you will be presented with the list of all found partitions including the actual and the lost ones. By selecting each one you may click on "p" to visualize its content and even copy it. If you did not find the partition you're looking for select "Deeper search".

Caution! If you select "write" the actual partition table of your HDD will be overwritten with selected partition scheme you chose in the results page. Obviously, this is suggested in case one need to revert its HDD to an earlier stage with everything back (Partitions and data) as if it was before.